# I am your learner and you are my mentor. question tag?

Tags: sentence-patterns, complex-sentences, question-tags

I would like to know  whether there is a question tag for compound sentences.

There are question tags for complex sentences.For example:

*I said that you were lazy.Didn't I?*

What is the question tag for the sentences given below.

*1.I am your learner and you are my mentor*

*2.English is difficult and I know It.*

Comment: You could go with, “Right?”  :-)

Comment: A question tag just has to match any preceding matrix clause that it makes sense to question-tag. In this case, that can be either of the two clauses making up the compound sentence, or it can be the entire compound sentence as a whole; you’d use different tags for each of those three options. So no, there isn’t ***a*** question tag for compound sentences; there are as many as it makes sense to have.

Comment: Your questions are probably too basic for this site. Please consider posting on  [English Language Learners.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 'English is difficult and I know it!' can't have a tag question, as 'and I know it' is an idiom meaning 'and that's the final word'. //  'I am your learner and you are my mentor' can only take a non-specific question tag like 'Correct?' or 'Isn't that the case?' // 'I am your learner ... and you are my mentor' takes the in-sentence tag for the second main clause:  'I am your learner ... and you are my mentor, aren't you?'

Comment: @Cascabel.Do you think that all of my questions are very basic? you must not fo get  that I have asked some very popular questions

Comment: You might take note of the last sentence in the answer from Kris..."Why was there a doubt?"

Comment: @Cascabel.All thse questions tags are correct to certain level. can  you show question tags for compound sentences in any standard book.I know question tags for each clause.But how a  question tag  can be used for two clauses.Complex  sentence is some what different. we may say  right, correct etc for this sentence

Comment: @Cascabel Edwin and Janus tried to clarify my doubt.They did not insult me. you are different.why don't you answer and clarify doubt.You always  comment but don't answer much.I can also make comments which are in no way helpful to the original poster or othet users

Comment: BTW, "your learner" is not how we'd say it, we'd say "your student".

Comment: @Barmar. why should we not say learner.I know we say that your student

Comment: See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your+learner%2Cyour+student&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20learner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20student%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cyour%20learner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20student%3B%2Cc0 The recent uses are only part of the phrase "your learner's permit", although older uses are like yours.

Comment: @Barmar, actually, it's very, very common these days to hear the word  _mentee_, which is actually in dictionaries (I just looked to make sure).

Comment: @IsabelArcher A teacher is not the same as a mentor, although there's some overlap.

Comment: @Barmar, you're absolutely right. I was going on the assumption that the word already there that was meant to stick was _mentor_; hence, _learner_ would become _mentee_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on meta.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A case like
"English is difficult and I know it."
can take one of three tags:

1. Isn't **that** so? ("English is difficult and I know it")
2. Isn't **it**? ("English is difficult")
3. Don't **I**?  ("I know it")

Why was there a doubt?

Comment: @Kris.Is there any rule for this.I have not seen a question tag for a compound sentence. I think we can make  two question tags which are not fully correct

Comment: There's no rule that a compound sentence should not have a question tag, either.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.Is it worth down voting(not you)

Comment: @kris.You commented that it was very  to answer.Your answer was down voted.. What is the correct  question tag for my sentence?

Comment: my question was downvoted and the answer was downvoted too.I hope somebody will answer and get an upvote.Then I agree that it  was a correct answer and right question tag.